# X propagation in gate level simulation

Tags: netlist

I want to know the behavior of gate level simulation with below condition:

OR cell with 2 inputs:  A = x, B = 1

MUX 2to1 with 3 inputs: A0 = 1, A1 = x, S  = 0 (Select A0)

What is the output (1 or X) in above case ?

Is there any option in VCS tool to set the output to X for above cases in gate level netlist ?

Thank in advance.